# Error in strsplit(x, split = "") : non-character argument

Tags: r

I'm trying to use `protr` package in r but I got error when I tried to extract amino acid composition  from the sequence as the following:

```
require(protr) 
x = readFASTA(system.file('protseq/P00750.fasta',   package='protr'))
extractAAC(x)
# Error in strsplit(x, split = "") : non-character argument
```

how can I fix this error?

Comment: Please check the `str(x)` The `strsplit` works only `character` vectors.  So you may need to convert to `character` class.

Comment: str(x)
List of 1
 $ sp|P00750|TPA_HUMAN: chr "MDAMKRGLCCVLLLCGAVFVSPSQEIHARFRRGARSYQVICRDEKTQMIYQQHQSWLRPVLRSNRVEYCWCNSGRAQCHSVPVKSCSEPRCFNGGTCQQALYFSDFVCQCPEGFAGKCCEIDTRATC"| __truncated__

Comment: In that case do `strsplit(x[[1]], "")`

Comment: how can i  convert it to character

Comment: The list element is already a character.  Please check that you showed `chr`

Comment: Specifically it is a list of one item that has a name of "sp|P00750|TPA_HUMAN"

Comment: strsplit(x[[1]], "")
[[1]]
  [1] "M" "D" "A" "M" "K" "R" "G" "L" "C" "C" "V" "L" "L" "L" "C" "G" "A" "V" "F" "V" "S" "P" "S"
 [24] "Q" "E" "I" "H" "A" "R" "F" "R" "R" "G" "A" "R" "S" "Y" "Q" "V" "I" "C" "R" "D" "E" "K" "T"

Comment: yes it's a character but I still unable to get the amino acid composition

Comment: do u know another way to get amino acid compostion for that squence using different library

Comment: Your question seems to be about fixing the error in `strsplit` and the below solution does that.  I don't know the rules of extracting the amino acid composition and it was not showed in your post.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that 'x' is a `list` of `length` 1.  We can extract the first element and then do the `strsplit`

```
strsplit(x[[1]], "")
```